# how to position nested list items?

Tags: css, html, html-lists, css-position

Well I'm a web design newbie. Any help would be appreciated.

I'm learning html and css by doing a live project and got stuck in positioning nested list items.

My web browser render look like this.

[image]
My HTML:

```
<nav class="nav-sidebar">
<ul class="sidebar-ul">
    <li class="sidebar-parent">parent-item-1
        <ul class="sidebar-sublist">
            <li class="sidebar-children">child 1</li>
            <li class="sidebar-children">child 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-parent">parent-item-2
        <ul class="sidebar-sublist">
            <li class="sidebar-children">child 1</li>
            <li class="sidebar-children">child 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-parent">parent-item-3
        <ul class="sidebar-sublist">
            <li class="sidebar-children">child 1</li>
            <li class="sidebar-children">child 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

My CSS:

for the nav side bar

```
.nav-sidebar{
width: 250px;
background: #444444;
position: fixed;
height: 100%;}
```

for the parent li

```
.sidebar-parent{
display: block;
width: auto;
padding-right: 5px;
padding-left: 20px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #211D1D;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 1em;
font-family: helvetica;
text-decoration: none;
background: #2D2828;}
```

for the children li

```
.sidebar-children{
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: lowercase;
color: #efefef;
background: #000000;
padding-right: 5px;
padding-left: 20px;
width: auto;
display: block;}
```

How can I position the children to align to the extreme left of the sidebar? At least just below the parent `li`?

Thank you so much for helping out, and sorry for my horrible English and code. Thanks for any help.

Comment: lol i feel like the little girl in Pixar's short film 'One Man Band', like which answer to choose the best. thank you everybody who helped me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset the default styles applied by the browser to `ul` tags.

```
.sidebar-sublist{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Also remove the left padding from `.sidebar-parent`.

Comment: thank you! it works. so simple, the lesson is to position the sub ul. thanks.

Comment: No problem, glad I helped. Feel free to mark the question as answered for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

In your markup, you could add the following to your CSS and it should do what I think you're asking for:

```
.sidebar-sublist { padding-left: 0; }
```

If you want the nested items to be completely flush with the parent items, then you can modify this part of your code:

```
.sidebar-children{
  padding-left: 20px; /* remove this if you want these flush with parent */
}
```

[Here's a fiddle showing the first change](http://jsfiddle.net/UwHYf/) (and you can edit the padding-left too):

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove the padding from classes `.sidebar-parent` and `.sidebar-children` and give a margin:0 to `ul` element.
Here is the modified CSS code.

```
.sidebar-children{
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: lowercase;
color: #efefef;
background: #000000;
display: block;}

.sidebar-parent{
display: block;
width: auto;

border-bottom: 1px solid #211D1D;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 1em;
font-family: helvetica;
text-decoration: none;
background: #2D2828;}

.nav-sidebar{
width: 250px;
background: #444444;
position: fixed;
height: 100%;}

.sidebar-ul, .sidebar-sublist{margin:0; padding:0;}
```

Please check the Demo link.

```
http://jsbin.com/puqaloya/1/edit
```

Comment: John please accept the answer so other people can get benefited from this example.